# Column Chart: All series on a given axis must be of the same data type

Tags: google-visualization

What am i doing wrong with the following code to get an error `All series on a given axis must be of the same data type`

```
function drawVisualization(){
        var performanceJson = $.ajax({
            url : "{% url json_data %}",
            type:"GET",
            dataType: "json",
            cache: false,
            async: false}).responseJSON;

        var performanceData = new google.visualization.DataTable();
        performanceData.addColumn('string', 'Question');
        performanceData.addColumn('string', 'Headings');
        performanceData.addColumn('number', 'TotalScore');
        performanceData.addColumn('number', 'Score');
        performanceData.addRows(performanceJson);

        var performanceOptions = {
            title : 'Performance Report',
            subtitle: 'Based on a scale of 1 to 7',
            hAxis : {title:'Question', titleTextStyle:{color:'red'}},
            vAxis : {title:'Scores'},
        };
        var chart = new google.visualization.ColumnChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
        chart.draw(performanceData, performanceOptions);
    }
```

The performanceJson variable has the value:

```
 [["No. of people", "Area", 6, 1], ["Scholars", "Standard", 12, 2], ["Co-ordination", "Standard", 18, 14]]
```

Comment: Hi! Could you paste your code to http://plnkr.co/ ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For a ColumnChart all columns(except the first) have to be of type `number`.

Column #2 is of type `string`, column#3 and column #4 are of type `number`, so the error-message should be clear.

I'm not sure for what column #2 is good for, but you may not use this column as `data`-column

You may e.g. use this column as `annotation`:

```js
google.load('visualization', '1', {packages: ['corechart', 'bar']});
google.setOnLoadCallback(drawVisualization);

function drawVisualization(){
        var performanceJson = [["No. of people", "Area", 6, 1], 
                               ["Scholars", "Standard", 12, 2], 
                               ["Co-ordination", "Standard", 18, 14]];

        var performanceData = new google.visualization.DataTable();
        performanceData.addColumn('string', 'Question');
        performanceData.addColumn({type:'string',role:'annotation'});
        performanceData.addColumn('number', 'TotalScore');
        performanceData.addColumn('number', 'Score');
        performanceData.addRows(performanceJson);

        var performanceOptions = {
            title : 'Performance Report',
            subtitle: 'Based on a scale of 1 to 7',
            hAxis : {title:'Question', titleTextStyle:{color:'red'}},
            vAxis : {title:'Scores'},
        };
        var chart = new google.visualization.ColumnChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
        chart.draw(performanceData, performanceOptions);
    }
```

```html
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
  <div id="chart_div"></div>
```